# Excluding specific words from token_wordstem()?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

Is there a way to prespecify words that will not be stemmed in quanteda? Have looked and it seems there isn't but wanted to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: I can answer this precisely if you supply a reproducible example and your desired output. Yes it’s simple in this case to guess, but it’s good form to learn how to ask a SO question. In short, though, I’d suggest using `tokens_replace()` appending a _ suffix to each token you want unstemmed, then stemming, then removing the _ suffix.